# In Javascript Regex, how do I match hash tags, but not with the HTML code?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is how I get the tags of a body of text.

```
var tags =  body.match(/#([a-z0-9]+)/gi);
```

However, if the sentence is:

```
The brown #fox jumped over &#8216; fence.
```

The regex above will treat "8216;" as a tag, which is what I do not want. I only want "fox" as a tag.

Note: I just want a basic regex solution.

Comment: Note that not all hashtags are ASCII. Example: https://twitter.com/#!/search/%23%E4%BB%8A%E6%97%A5%E3%81%AF

Comment: @icktoofay how would I use regex to handle all utf-8 chars?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a little tricky. JavaScript leaves some Unicode processing to you. You probably want to see [Twitter's official JavaScript library for text processing](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js/blob/master/twitter-text.js) to see how it matches hashtags. (Spoiler: It's complex.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Try this one:**

```
/(^#|\s#)([a-z0-9]+)/gi
```

**LIVE DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/NpjyR/

or this:

```
/(^#|[^&]#)([a-z0-9]+)/gi   //this will exclude every &#
```

Comment: @TIMEX, yes because I forgot the `#`. fixed. See demo. It works.

Comment: @TIMEX, it means a space, so that it can exclude `&#`.

Comment: This doesn't work for other languages. #état for example isn't matched.

Comment: See this fiddle: http://regexr.com/3bevj, I'm trying to make it NOT find blank space before #tag, and not find #tag inside a URL or when proceeded with non-whitespace i.e. number or slash. `/(#[a-z\d]+)/g`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have access to the DOM, you could use the DOM to decode the HTML and then match on the text content:

```
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = body;
var tags = temp.textContent.match(/#([a-z0-9]+)/gi);
```

Comment: I'm on node.js, so I just want a basic regex solution.

Comment: @TIMEX, did you try my answer?

Comment: @TIMEX: You could try [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), if you don't mind adding a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

```
#([a-z0-9]+)\b(?!;)
```

Answer (score 0):

| liked | unliked |
| --- | --- |
| *true* | false |

| i | others |
| --- | --- |
| true | null |

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).